# How can I rename strings based on other strings that have a different prefix?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I have a google spreadsheet (which I have as a csv as well) that I have stored with the column of names I want to use (the source), on the first rows and the names I want to change in the first column (the target, from line 2).

```
#1 - Giorgi Margvelashvili,#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili,#1 - United National Movement,#10 - Levan Chachua,#10 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,#10 - People's Party,#11 - Akaki Asatiani,#11 - Giorgi Chikhladze,#11 - Our Country,#11 - Sportsman's Union,#12 - Future Georgia,#12 - Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party,#13 - Mamuka Melikishvili,#13 - Merab Kostava Society,#13 - Teimuraz Mzhavia,#14 - Freedom Party,#14 - Georgian Group,#14 - Labour Council of Georgia,#15 - Avtandil Margiani,#15 - Mikheil Saluashvili,#17 - Nestan Kirtadze,#17 - Sergo Javakhidze,#17 - Tamaz Bibiluri,#2 - Davit Bakradze,#2 - Georgian Dream,#2 - Levan Gachechiladze,#2 - United Opposition,#20 - Mamuka Chokhonelidze,#20 - Nugzar Avaliani,#22 - Kartlos Gharibashvili,#22 - Teimuraz Bobokhidze,#3 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili,#3 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#3 - Free Georgia,#3 - Freedom Party,#3 - Future Georgia,#3 - Georgian Group,#3 - Labour,#3 - Labour Council of Georgia,#3 - Merab Kostava Society,#3 - Movement for Fair Georgia,#3 - National Democratic Party of Georgia,#3 - New Rights,#3 - Nino Burjanadze,#3 - People's Party,#3 - Public Movement,#3 - Republican party,#3 - Sportsman's Union,#4 - Labour,#4 - Republican party,#4 - Shalva Natelashvili,#5 - Christian Democratic Alliance,#5 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze,#5 - Georgian Politics,#5 - Giorgi Targamadze,#5 - Labour,#5 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,#5 - New Rights,#5 - Our Country,#5 - Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists,#5 - Sportsman's Union,#5 - Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party,#6 - Free Georgia,#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili,#6 - Koba Davitashvili,#6 - Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists,#7 - Giorgi Liluashvili,#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia,#7 - Movement for Fair Georgia,#7 - Sportsman's Union,#8 - Christian Democratic Alliance,#8 - National Democratic Party of Georgia,#8 - Zurab Kharatishvili,#9 - Georgian Politics,#9 - Nino Chanishvili,#9 - Public Movement
Giorgi Margvelashvili,Georgian Dream,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Mikheil Saakashvili,United National Movement,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
United National Movement,United National Movement,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Nino Chanishvili,Initiative Group,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

As far as the target is similar but still a bit different (`#number - sameNameAsTheTarget`), how can I rename a string based on another string which have a different prefix ?

I tried this in javascript (but an answer in Python is fine for me too) but we only pass the test if the source and target are exactly the same.

Based on Barmar answer I made this one because google script might have some restrictions on the libraries one can use :

```
/**
This function will rename the cells of the first columns if they have an elment of the first row 
@customFunction
*/
function RENAMECELL() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  for (var row = 2; row < 60; row++) {
    var name = activeSheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    console.log(name);
    for (var col = 1; col < 50; col++) {
      if (activeSheet.getRange(1,col).getValue().indexOf(name) !== -1) {
        activeSheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(activeSheet.getRange(1,col).getValue());
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All thanks to Bramar and Alan Wells. Yet I still have a few rows of the target column that aren't updated :

```
#1 - Giorgi Margvelashvili,Georgian Dream
#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili,United National Movement
#1 - United National Movement,United National Movement
Nino Chanishvili,Initiative Group
#11 - Sportsman's Union,Sportsman's Union
#14 - Georgian Group,Georgian Group
#20 - Mamuka Chokhonelidze,Initiative Group
#17 - Sergo Javakhidze,Movement for a Fair Georgia
#12 - Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party,Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party
#11 - Our Country,Our Country
#11 - Giorgi Chikhladze,Initiative Group
#13 - Merab Kostava Society,Merab Kostava Society
#13 - Mamuka Melikishvili,Initiative Group
#3 - Public Movement,Public Movement
#15 - Avtandil Margiani,Initiative Group
#14 - Labour Council of Georgia,Labour Council of Georgia
#10 - People's Party,People's Party
#11 - Akaki Asatiani,Union of Georgian Traditionalists
#17 - Nestan Kirtadze,Initiative Group
#20 - Nugzar Avaliani,Initiative Group
#17 - Tamaz Bibiluri,Initiative Group
#2 - Davit Bakradze,United National Movement
#2 - Georgian Dream,Georgian Dream
#2 - Levan Gachechiladze,Initiative Group
#2 - United Opposition,United Opposition
#13 - Teimuraz Mzhavia,Christian Democratic People's Party
#15 - Mikheil Saluashvili,Initiative Group
#22 - Kartlos Gharibashvili,Initiative Group
#22 - Teimuraz Bobokhidze,Initiative Group
#3 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili,Initiative Group
#3 - Christian-Democratic Movement,Christian-Democratic Movement
#14 - Labour Council of Georgia,Labour
#3 - Nino Burjanadze,Democratic Movement – United Georgia
Christian Democratic Alliance,Christian Democratic Alliance
#3 - New Rights,New Rights
Shalva Natelashvili,Labour Party
Davit Gamkrelidze,New Right
Giorgi Targamadze,Christian-Democratic Movement
#10 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia
#3 - Republican party,Republican party
#3 - Free Georgia,Free Georgia
Georgian Politics,Georgian Politics
Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili,Party of the Future
Koba Davitashvili,People's Party
#3 - Movement for Fair Georgia,Movement for Fair Georgia
Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists,Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists
Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia,Hope party
Zurab Kharatishvili,European Democrats
#12 - Future Georgia,Future Georgia
#10 - Levan Chachua,Initiative group    
#3 - National Democratic Party of Georgia,National Democratic Party of Georgia
#14 - Freedom Party,Freedom Party
Giorgi Liluashvili,Initiative group
```

Comment: Why are you comparing with `==` inside the `setValue()` argument?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `name`?

Comment: What do you mean by "rename"? It seems like you just want to replace the value, not rename anything.

Comment: Yes ! replace it, sorry I'm from a Python background and brand new to javascript @Barmar

Comment: What does the language have to do with it? You don't rename strings in Python, either.

Comment: Or change them, I need to transform the rows with, let say `Giorgi Margvelashvili` to `#1 - Giorgi Margvelashvili`. I tried to do it in javascript to learn the language

Comment: I thought you wanted to change it to `Georgian Dream`

Comment: You can use `str1.includes(str2)` to tell if one name is part of another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the cells in the first row. Then loop over the remaining rows. Use `.includes()` to test if the name in the first cell of that row is in the value from the cell from the first row. If it is, replace it with the value from the second cell.

```
for (int col = 1; col < 60; col++) {
    let name = activeSheet.getRange(1, col).getValue();
    for (int row = 2; row < 50; row++) {
        if (name.includes(activeSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue())) {
            activeSheet.getRange(1, col).setValue(activeSheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yet I had to change all `int` and `let` to `var`. Furthermore my script.google.com compiler tells me that there is no `includes` function

Comment: You can find a polyfill for `includes` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)